# How do I create a text underline animation?

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to make an `<a>` tag element animates in an underline on hover, similar to the first example on [this page](https://css-irl.info/animating-underlines/). Asking this almost feels stupid since the tutorial is RIGHT THERE, but something I'm doing isn't working and I'm not sure why.

Here's what I've got in my CSS

```
#about-text-box a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17pt;
    font-family: 'Silkscreen', cursive;
    color: #ECE0E7;
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #101400;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#about-text-box a:hover::after, #about-text-box a:focus::after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0.2em, 0);

}

#about-text-box a::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.1em;
    background-color: inherit;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few missing properties I noticed:

1. `content: ''` on `a::after` is missing. For a pseudo-element, the `content` property can be empty `""`, but must be specified.
2. `position: relative` need to be on `a` because pseudo-element `a::after` is using `position: relative`.
3. `a::after` is using `background-color: inherit` but does not seems to have any value that can be inherited. I gave it a value `hotpink` for now, but this can be customized to any color.
4. I added `cursor: pointer` on `a` so it is more matching your desired result.

Hope this will help!

Example: (see live demo with button below)

```css
#about-text-box {
  display: flex;
}

#about-text-box a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17pt;
  font-family: "Silkscreen", cursive;
  color: #ece0e7;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #101400;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#about-text-box a:hover::after,
#about-text-box a:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0.2em, 0);
}

#about-text-box a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1em;
  background-color: hotpink;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="about-text-box">
  <a>Hover this link</a>
</div>
```